Computing residue at infinity
Let $g$ be holomorphic function in $G = \{|z| > 100\}$ where
$$g (z) = \frac{z^{99}}{\prod_{k=1}^{100} (z-k)}$$
I would like to compute $Res(g,\infty)$. By definition
$$Res(g,\infty) = -Res(\frac{1}{z^2}g(\frac{1}{z}), 0)$$
So for circle $C_R$ with $R>100$ large so that all zeros are inside we have
\begin{align*}
    Res(\frac{1}{z^2}g(\frac{1}{z}), 0) &=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_{\frac{1}{R}}} \frac{(1/z)^{99}}{\prod_{k=1}^{100} (\frac{1}{z}-k)} \frac{-1}{z^2}dz \\ &= \frac{-1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_{\frac{1}{R}}} \frac{z^{100}}{z^{101} \prod_{k=1}^{100} (1-kz)} dz \\
    &= \frac{-1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_{\frac{1}{R}}} \frac{1}{z \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{100} (1-kz)} dz
\end{align*}
At this point I do not know how to evaluate this integral without computing all of the residues separately which is what I am trying to avoid by computing a single residue at infinity in the first place.

The function $f(z)=\prod_{k=1}^{100}(1-kz)^{-1}$ is holomorphic for $|z|< {1\over 100}.$ Therefore when $r<{1\over 100}$ by the Cauchy formula we have $$-{1\over 2\pi i}\int_{C_r}{f(z)\over z}\,dz=-f(0)=-1$$ Another way $$-\lim_{z\to 0}z{1\over z^2}g(z^{-1})=-\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=-f(0)=-1$$

Thank you for your response!

Note that
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}g\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) 
     = \frac{1}{z} \prod_{k=1}^{100} \frac{1}{1-kz} 
     = \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1 - \mathcal{O}(z)} 
     = \frac{1 + \mathcal{O}(z)}{z},
$$
using the geometric series, hence
$$
\operatorname{Res}(g(z),\infty) = -\operatorname{Res}(f(z),0) = -1.
$$

Thank you for your response!
